# Type created with compilation errors in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have tried to run two script in oracle sqlplus

```
create type virus_Statistic_t as object(
    vDate date,
    infection int,
    dead int,
    recovered int
)
/
```

Above script run without any errors.

But after that when I tried to run this script

```
create type countries_t as object(
    Province_or_State varchar2(50),
    Country_or_Region varchar2(100),
    Lat Number(10,0),
    Long Number(10,0),
    virus virus_Statistic_t
)
/
```

This give me some warnings

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
5/1      PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not related to subtype.

It is error because you are using the **oracle reserved keyword** as field name: `Long Number(10,0),`

Change it to something like: `Long_ Number(10,0),` and everything will work fine.

Comment: Or use the full names `latitude` and `longitude` rather than appending a random character to the end.